# How to setup an ajax call using symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have this simply ajax/jquery call to a symfony2 controller/action

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://symfony.local:8080/app_dev.php/api/searches/guitar.json',
    success: function(results) {

    }
});
```

I'd need to change the first part of the url 'http://symfony.local:8080/app_dev.php/api/searches/guitar.json' in order to make it independent from the front controller I'm using. How can I achieve this?

Comment: url shuold be generated, but not hardcoded

Comment: [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)

Comment: Is this code inserted into js file or into twig/html one?

Comment: yes I know the url should be generated, how to do this is exactly what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you supplying the whole URL? You could omit the domain part so that the path is relative:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/app_dev.php/api/searches/guitar.json',
    success: function(results) {

    }
});
```

Second, you can set up the prefix for your AJAX calls in a Symfony view:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
{% if app.environment == 'dev' %}
    var root = '/app_dev.php/';
{% else %}
    var root = '/';
{% endif %} 
</script>
```

I've introduced a `window.root` variable here. You can use it in your scripts then:

```
// ...
url: root + '/api/searches/guitar.json',
// ...
```

And as suggested in the comments, the best way here would be passing the URL to your scripts with a separate routing provider for JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I supply the whole url just as an example. then, in my code app.environment is not defined. what I need to to is to create a relative url for my ajax call, in a similar way as when I generate a path in the template like this: <a href="{{ path('blog_show', {'slug': 'my-blog-post'}) }}">

Answer (score 0):

You could set the url as the href and catch it or set it as some of data tag.

**As href**

Your link

```
<a href="{{ path('your_route') }}" class="ajax-link">Link</a>
```

And the javascript

```
$('a.ajax-link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Stop link updating page

    var href = $(this).attr('href);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: href,
        ....
    });
});
```

**Or as a data field**

Your link

```
<a data-href="{{ path('your_route') }}" class="ajax-link">Link</a>
```

And the javascript

```
$('a.ajax-link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Stop link updating page

    var href = $(this).data('href);

    ... see above ...
});
```

With either of these ways there is no use for FOSJsRouting or hard coded routes.